# Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint even with no child data?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, delete, truncate

With a `ON DELETE RESTRICT` restriction, I understand that you can't delete a row in the parent table if a reference exist in the child table, but is it expected behavior that even if the child table is actually empty you still cannot `TRUNCATE` the parent table?

Comment: `TRUNCATE` will fail even when `ON DELETE RESTRICT` is not specified. This operation uses fast records deleting technique which does not include FK checks.

Comment: Did you try SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; before running the truncate/delete statement?

Comment: <snide-comment>Yet another reason why FKs may be more trouble than benefit</snide-comment>

Comment: @RickJames Are you recommending to ditch FKs altogether?

Comment: FKs are designed for a small set of 'normal' integrity tests.  `TRUNCATE` is a drastic action that is outside of the 'norm'.  Please explain why you need to Truncate; perhaps there is another action that would achieve the goals _and_ keep FKs.

Comment: @RickJames I'm just using `TRUNCATE` in unit tests in the application layer